# why am I getting the error "error executing aapt "

Tags: android, android-layout, facebook-android-sdk

I'm getting the error executing aapt :return code 1073741819 due to which
.apk file is not generated how to fix this. How to fix if r.java file is missing

Comment: Check your codes first to see if there are any errors. The **R.java** won't be created if there are compilation errors in your codes.

Comment: @ChuongPham In my problem window I have only 1 error" error executing aapt :return code 1073741819" I don't understand what's this error about and how to fix it. Please help me out

Comment: What IDE are you using? If you are using Eclipse you should try cleaning your projects.

Comment: Check your XML files and make sure that all **@+id** references have a corresponding entry in **strings.xml**. Also enable Lint error checking for your Android project so you can see if you have errors with your XML files.

Comment: I had this error too, exactly this: `Error executing aapt: return code -1073741819 Path: appname Location: line 1 Type: Android ADT Problem`. I searched during almost one hour any ids, any spaces, any close tags, anything which seemed weird. The only thing that resolved my issue was to delete the last xml that I created. And the problem gone.

Comment: in my case, it was a missing icon in the resources.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a syntax or formatting error in one of the XML files.  I just got this error code (it's actually negative), and I checked all the `@string` references and they were OK.  Eventually I figured out it was because of this item in a menu XML file:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_stop"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_stop"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom | withText"
    android:title="@string/action_stop"/>
```

However, the spaces around the `|` apparently aren't valid (XML isn't Java...).  Eclipse didn't catch it as an error, but `aapt` crashed without giving a reason when it saw it.  Not particularly graceful handling, by both Eclipse and `aapt`.  Removing the extra spaces made everything work.

The problem with missing entries in `strings.xml` apparently produces error code `-1073741816`, not `-1073741819`.  You have to look closely, but the last digit is different.

I'm not saying the problem is definitely some sort of syntax error.  But it's another possibility that could be investigated.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I had deleted a @string entry that was being referenced in a menu  node xml resource.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and spent time trying to find a solution.

Finally the solution for this error which is: -1073741819 ( check the digits ) was a library was missing from: Properties -> Android -> Library
I just added the missing libraries and got this error resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. What helped me was changing the Project Build Target

Properties->Android->Project Build Target