# Rebuilding R.java file in Eclipse

Tags: android

I accidentally deleted the generated java file R.java. Is there a way to rebuild this file as my project cant run or debug?
 I tried cleaning the project then rebuilding it but that doesnt work.

Comment: Project/Clean: your R will be automatically recreated if Build Automatically is selected.

Comment: clean the project its working for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick way:
Right click -> Restore from local history.

A window with all the changes you made should appear.

EDIT:

If there are any errors in the layout or any resource files the `R` file will not be restored after a clean - build

Comment: That worked but i am still getting an "Error executing aapt...." message. what can i do about this?

Comment: @nemesis22 Try cleaning it

Comment: Just did and it deleted the R file that was restored.

Comment: ok i restored from local history then instead of cleaning i restarted Eclipse and it now seems to work with no errors. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Without having more information, the answer is that R.java WILL be re-generated. Unless you have a compilation error.

Errors in layouts can also hinder R.java from being generated. So check that also.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean and build the project to regenerate.

Answer (score 0):

Gen files are regenerated automatically if you have the Project->Build automatically option is checked. If it's not checked, you need to rebuild it manually by Project->Clean...

Comment: One thing to consider, you need to have no error on your Resource files or your platform won't generate your R.java file.

Comment: The only error its showing is "error executing appt...." is that the tool that generates the R file?

Comment: It's clearly a compiling problem. You need to re check if you have any problems in your xml files. Maybe a reference mistake? Like you used @id instead of @+id while you don't have the id reference?

Comment: You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20788721/why-am-i-getting-the-error-error-executing-aapt , similar problem that's been fixed by controlling your xmls.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure ther isnt any error in a XML file, for example your layour files or Manifest. Clean your project after that.